# Restrict a Quill editor to a single-line input?

Tags: quill

Is there a way to restrict the editor to a single-line input? Much like `input` vs. `textarea`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no officially supported way. You could use the keyboard API to ignore enters, but there are other ways to introduce new lines, such as pasting. Feel free to submit a [feature request](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues) and if there is enough interest it may be added in the future.